# k6 reports with today date

Tags: javascript, performance, k6

I have my tests in k6 - performance tests. 
I need add today date to html report:

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { sleep } from 'k6';
import { htmlReport } from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benc-uk/k6-reporter/main/dist/bundle.js";
import { textSummary } from "https://jslib.k6.io/k6-summary/0.0.1/index.js";

export function handleSummary(data) {
  return {
    "./report/xxxxx.html": htmlReport(data),
    stdout: textSummary(data, { indent: " ", enableColors: true }),
  };
}


export const options = {
  ext: {
    loadimpact: {
      distribution: {
        "amazon:us:ashburn": { loadZone: "amazon:us:ashburn", percent: 100 },
      },
    },
  },
  stages: [
    { target: 5, duration: "5s" },
    { target: 10, duration: "10s" },
    { target: 5, duration: "5s" },

   ],
   thresholds: {
    "http_req_duration": ["p(95)<5000"],
    "http_req_failed": ["rate<0.01"],
  }

};


export default function () {
  const res = http.get('https://xxxx/');
  sleep(1);
}
```

I don`t know, how I can add today date to title of report
I try with add today day.

Thanks!

Comment: `new Date()` gives you a date object of the current date and time. `new Date().toISOString()` will format it as ISO string. Is that what you are asking? If not, please clarify and show where the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are experiencing might come from JavaScript's way of creating objects with dynamic keys.

So what you can do is either using the current date object directly:

```
export function handleSummary(data) {
  return {
    [`./report/${new Date()}.html`]: htmlReport(data),
    stdout: textSummary(data, { indent: " ", enableColors: true }),
  };
}
```

This then will create a file like: `Wed Oct 05 2022 10:05:44 GMT+0200 (CEST).html`. As that is not really a good readable format, we can also implement the suggestion of [@knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) using `.toISOString()`.

```
export function handleSummary(data) {
  return {
    [`./report/${new Date().toISOString()}.html`]: htmlReport(data),
    stdout: textSummary(data, { indent: " ", enableColors: true }),
  };
}
```

This then will result in something like `2022-10-05T08:09:54.005Z.html`. You can of course also format the Date string in any way you prefer.